# Figuring out how many rows/columns there should be based off of an int

Tags: javascript

Here is the challenge:

```
/**
 * Determines how many rows and columns your garden will
 * need to be closest to a square given a number of seeds.
 *
 * @param {number} seedCount - The number of seeds in your
 * seed packet.
 * @return {array} - [rows, columns] needed for your grid
 * layout (for example [4, 5] represents a 4 row x 5 column
 * grid)
*/
function grid(seedCount) {

  // Solution here

}
```

This is NOT coding homework, its one of those coding websites and idk why but this question really has me stumped, I am probably just overthinking it but I would like to know the solution...

EDIT: First solution (Did not work)

```
function grid(seedCount) {
    /* Enter your solution here! */
    var num1 = Math.sqrt(seedCount)
    num1 = Math.round(num1)

    while(seedCount % num1 != 0){
        num1++

    }

    num2 = seedCount / num1
    var Arr = [num1,num2]
    return Arr 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's take into account the constraints of this question:

- The garden must be able to accommodate 1 seed per square.
- The garden should be small enough that there's a minimal number of wasted spaces.
- The garden should be as close as possible to a perfect square.

From this, we get 3 basic concepts:

- `Number of seeds ≤ length × width`
- `|length × width - seedCount|` is as close to `0` as possible
- `|length - width|` is as close to `0` as possible

Working off of our third constraint, we can determine our length by taking the square root of the number of seeds we have and finding the next highest integer:

```js
const length = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(seedCount))
```

Once we have the length, we can find the width by dividing the number of seeds by the length. However, since this can give us a non-integer number (indicating that we couldn't perfectly divide), finding the next highest integer should give us the width:

```js
const width = Math.ceil(seedCount / length)
```

Now that we have our dimensions, all we have to do is assemble them into an array and return them!

```js
const gridCount = seedCount =>
{
    const length = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(seedCount))
    const width = Math.ceil(seedCount / length)
    return [length, width]
}
```

Comment: Wow.... Great job! Could you expand on how this works exactly?

Likewise this was the "1.1 BEGINNER" level question, literally the first one... Would you say that this is a little bit harder than a regular question? Or do I just need to getgud

Comment: This problem isn't ultimately too hard, but it does take a bit of thinking. Basically, we want to find some integers `n` and `m` where `n * m` is as close to `seedCount` as possible, as well as being as close to `n == m` as possible. To do this, we first get the lowest perfect square that's greater than the seedCount (where we get `length`). To get our width, we just need to divide `seedCount` by our length. However, since this will get us a floating point number (aka not an integer), we pass it to `Math.ceil()` to get the next highest integer.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it worked for you! :D

Comment: I went ahead and expanded the explanation in the answer itself